# SpringBoot : JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.new_model.BenzenoidCriterions`

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, jackson

I'm using SpringBoot and I have the following controller:

```
@Autowired
BenzenoidService service;

@PostMapping("/find_benzenoid")
public List<Benzenoid> find(@RequestBody BenzenoidCriterions benzenoidData) {
    Triplet<String[], Operator[], Object[]> arrays = buildArrays(benzenoidData);
    return service.findBenzenoids(arrays.getX(), arrays.getY(), arrays.getZ());
}
```

And the following @RequestBody BenzenoidCriterions:

```
public class BenzenoidCriterions {
    
    private String id = "";
    private String name = "";
    private String nbHexagons = "";
    private String nbCarbons = "";
    private String nbHydrogens = "";
    private String irregularity = "";
    
    public BenzenoidCriterions() {
        super();
    }
    
    public BenzenoidCriterions(String id, String name, String nbHexagons,
            String nbCarbons, String nbHydrogens, String irregularity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.nbHexagons = nbHexagons;
        this.nbCarbons = nbCarbons;
        this.nbHydrogens = nbHydrogens;
        this.irregularity = irregularity;
    }

    // getters
}
```

Actually, it is working when I provide a JSON input with all the fields of BenzenoidCriterions, but when I skip one or many fields in the input, I got the following error message:

```
2022-10-25 13:53:37.409  WARN 25509 --- [nio-8894-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.new_model.BenzenoidCriterions`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.ValueInstantiationException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.new_model.BenzenoidCriterions`, problem: `java.lang.NullPointerException`
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 91]]
```

The problem seems to be related to Jackson, which is supposed to parse the JSON input and convert it into an instance of BenzenoidCriterions.

Does someone have the solution for this, please ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Jackson provides an annotation that can be used on class level like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BenzenoidCriterions
{
    ...
}
```

This way Jackson will ignore missing fields.